# PHP Decode Square Multidimensional JSON Array

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

hi i'm trying to parse square multidimensional array with php 
but i'm unable to get actual values

```
[
   {
        'name':'john',
        'age':'26'
   },
   {
        'name':'smith',
        'age':'27'
   },
   {
       'name':'naveed',
       'age':'29'
   }
]
```

how can i parse this json via php

here i tried following method..

```
$json = file_get_contents('my json url');
$decoded = json_decode($json);
foreach ($decoded as $val){
 echo $val->name[0];
}
```

Comment: are you sure thats single quotes? thats supposed to be double quotes in order to be valid. after getting the valid quotes, just ditch that zero index. and thats solved

Comment: Remove the `[0]` from `$val->name[0]`...

Comment: i got it ... i just converted single quote to double thats the problem ...